# Separate website with same domain name by adding /organizationx path at the url

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have 2 containers websites that listen to `app1.com/` and `app2.com/` and they can have the same endpoints.

I want to create an Nginx proxy to separate organizations:

- `http://<proxy-ip>/organisation1` to listen from here `app1.com/`
- `http://<proxy-ip>/organisation2` to listen from here `app2.com/`

Users should see `http://<proxy-ip>/organisation1/movies` and all `css/js` to be forwarded to `http://<proxy-ip>/organisation1/css/a.css`

The location in app is `app1.com/movies` and `app1.com/css/a.css` etc.

The problem is that rewrite method doesn't forward the `/organisationX`.

How to add and forward this to URL if the location doesn't exist in the real app?

```
server {
   listen 80;
   location /organisation1 {
       proxy_set_header   Host $host;
       proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $host/organisation1;
       proxy_pass         http:app1.com

   }
   location /organisation2 {
       proxy_set_header   Host $host;
       proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $host/organisation2;
       proxy_pass         http:app2.com
   }
}
```

Comment: So the final container should be called like this `http://app.com/movies` and this `http://app.com/css/a.css`? What does happen right now? Your problem is not clear to me

Answer (score 0):

[ngx_http_rewrite_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) will help you

See manual:

> If the specified regular expression matches a request URI, URI is changed as specified in the `_replacement_` string.

Try this code:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   location /organisation1 {
       rewrite ^/organisation1/(.*) /$1 break;       
       ...
       proxy_pass         http:app1.com

   }
   location /organisation2 {
       rewrite ^/organisation2/(.*) /$1 break;       
       ...
       proxy_pass         http:app2.com
   }
}
```